# Observer over a network

Tags: c#, observer-pattern

I want to have an event driven architecture where the event consumer (subscriber/observer) and the event producer (publisher/subject) are over a distributed geography.

Is there something in .NET that relays events over a network seamlessly without my having to plumb into the implementation of the transport mechanism?

I recall Juval Lowy saying something about Enterprise Services in a DNR show 2 years or so ago but can't recall what that was.

Anyone know what I can use from the .NET framework to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with WCF and MSMQ. Tom Hollander has a [blog post on it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx). You could also look at solutions like TIBCO. If you fancy open source, [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is worth a look at too. If you're looking for a service bus, then [mass transit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/) is also an open source option. Mike Hadlow has [blogged about it here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/07/first-look-at-masstransit.html).

Comment: +1 for MSMQ. This is exactly what MSMQ, or an ESB that supports pub/sub, is designed for.

Comment: Isn't Tibco a little *overkill* for this particular question?

Comment: @Ty- what is wrong with Tibco, I know many people that use it successfully.

Comment: Rhino ESB and NServiceBus are other service bus implementations you could look into.

Comment: @Jamie- yes, those are two more popular ones.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something in .NET that relays
>   events over a network seamlessly
>   without my having to plumb into the
>   implementation of the transport
>   mechanism?

I believe this is where .NET Remoting ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.85).aspx)) comes into play. I'm no expert with it, but it looks like what you're looking for.

In addition to .NET Remoting, WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx)) may be a *better* alternative to Remoting. I have some experience with WebServices and little with WCF, but I would investigate these two .NET technologies.

Comment: Remoting is now considered legacy. WCF should be used instead.

Comment: I figured as such. I never used it but I didn't want to exclude it either. WCF WTF? :)

Comment: Implementing events over Remoting is considered bad practice. http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/net-remoting-faq/remotingusecases

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for MSMQ.  This article should help get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect job for an Erlang system ... or maybe use an AMCQ client like RabbitMQ, no?

Answer (score 1):

MSMQ would be a good way of doing this if you have configuration access.  WCF should be a reasonable alternative depending on how vital the messaging is.

Simple MSMQ example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mgpmyqueue.aspx